# Need clarity with the maximum modulus principle of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I was reading on the maximum modulus principle and I stumbled upon a

Theorem: *If a function $f$ is analytic and not constant in a given domain $D$, then $|f(z)|$ has no maximum value in $D$. That is, there is no point $z_0$ in the domain such that $|f(z)|\leq |f(z_0)|$ for all points $z$ in it.*

However, the author also says this:

*If a function $f$ that is analytic at each point in the interior of a closed bounded region $R$ is also continuous throughout $R$, then the modulus $|f(z)|$ has a maximum value somewhere in $R$. That is, there exists a nonnegative constant $M$ such that $|f(z)|\leq M$ for all points $z$ in $R$, and equality holds for at least one such point.*

**Question**:

I seem to have trouble wrapping my head around both statements being true. The theorem just means that $|f(z)|$ is a constant in the domain $D$. The author's note, which is practically the same conditions (unless I'm not seeing something), basically contradicts the theorem and says that there is a max. Can someone help clarify?

Comment: The crucial difference is that $D$ is open and $R$ is closed. If you combine the two, you can conclude that the maximum in the second case is attained on the boundary.

Answer (score 2):

The region is closed and bounded , so of course the maximum is obtained somewhere there by compactness and continuity.  The MMP asserts, however, that it is in fact obtained on the boundary of R.